# What are some (deep) reinforcement learning books for beginners?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, reference-request, resource-request

What are some books on reinforcement learning (RL) and deep RL for beginners?

I'm looking for something as friendly as the head first series, that breaks down every single thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction** by *Richard Sutton and Andrew Barto* is undoubtedly one of the best books, to begin with. Despite its age, the book is still the canonical introduction to reinforcement learning. It does require some patience, but I think it's very approachable and rigorous at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a book that is more beginner friendly than the Sutton and Barto book (which you should of course check out also), try out:

[Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands On](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1838826998)